# For loop total increments in loop, but when printing afterwards returns 0

Tags: javascript, loops, promise, axios

I'm creating an Alexa application that acts as a portfolio manager for stocks. I have a function which first retrieves all the stocks and the amount of stocks belonging to a user. For each of these stocks, I must query an API using axios to get the value of the stock, meaning the axios get statement is nested within the forEach loop. I then have a totalPrice variable, which is incremented using the total price of a stock; which is found by multiplying the price by the amount of stock x owned

At the end of the forEach loop I want to print the totalPrice which would be the whole value of a portfolio

When I print out the totalPrice within the request statement, it correctly adds previous total stock prices, but if I print the totalPrice after the forEach loop, it prints 0

```
var grandTotal = 0;
data.Items.forEach(function(element,index,array) {  
   var stock = element.Stock;
   var number = element.Number;
   var url = `www.api.com/${stock}`;

   const getDataValues = async url => {
     try {
      const response = await axios.get(url);
      const data = response.data;
      var Price = data.PRICE;
      return Price;
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

 let promiseObject = getDataValues(url);
 promiseObject.then(function(result) {
     var totalPriceofStocks = result * amount;
     grandTotal += totalPriceOfStocks;
     console.log(`{grandTotal}`);        // This bit accumulates correctly
 });
});
console.log(`The grand total is: ${grandTotal}`);
```

what's confusing me is that although the data is asynchronous, I thought that using `.then` would wait until the data is retrieved. This seems to be the case as while printing the total in the forEach loop this works. Something else which is interesting is that in the console, "The grand total is: 0" is printing first.

Comment: Well `.then()` does wait, in a sense, but the call to `.then()` returns immediately. The *callback* passed in to `.then()` is invoked only when the Promise is eventually resolved.

Comment: How do I then make it wait till the promise is resolved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use for..of loop instead of forEach in which await should work as expected

```
for (const element of data.Items) {
   var stock = element.Stock;
   var number = element.Number;
   var url = `www.api.com/${stock}`;

   const getDataValues = async url => {
     try {
      const response = await axios.get(url);
      const data = response.data;
      var Price = data.PRICE;
      return Price;
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

 const result = await getDataValues(url);
 var totalPriceofStocks = result * amount;
 grandTotal += totalPriceOfStocks;
 console.log(`{grandTotal}`);
}
```

Comment: I get an 'await is only valid in async function' using this method, to do with the result

Comment: You should have put `async` in front of the function containing this code!

Answer (score 1):

The console.log in the end prints 0 because it is executed immediately after your promises are initiated (and not finished yet).

In order to wait until all the promises have finished, then you can:

1. Store the promises in a list
2. Use [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all), which takes a list of promises as parameter, and resolves when all promises have resolved (in your case, when all axios requests are finished).

I have added a modified example of your code, to show how to do this. As I do not have your data I have not been able to test it, but hopefully it works.

```
const promises = []

const getDataValues = async url => {
  try {
    const response = await axios.get(url);
    const data = response.data;
    var Price = data.PRICE;
    return Price;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};

var grandTotal = 0;
data.Items.forEach(function(element,index,array) {  
  var stock = element.Stock;
  var number = element.Number;
  var url = `www.api.com/${stock}`;

  let promiseObject = getDataValues(url);
  promiseObject.then(function(result) {
    var totalPriceofStocks = result * amount;
    grandTotal += totalPriceOfStocks;
    console.log(`${grandTotal}`);        // This bit accumulates correctly
    return totalPriceOfStocks
  });
  promises.push(promiseObject)
});

Promise.all(promises)
  .then(function (resultValues) {
    console.log(`The grand total is: ${grandTotal}`);
    let resultSum = 0;
    resultValues.forEach(function (value) {
      resultSum += value;
    })
    console.log(`This is also the total: ${resultSum}`);
  })
```

Notice also that I have added a return value to your promise object. I have this to show an alternative way of accumulating the grand total rather than relying on a global value.
The logic behind this, is that when a Promise returns a value, that value is made available for the function passed to the 'then' chained function. In this case, where we use Promise.all, Promise.all passes a list of the promise's return values to its 'then' function. Therefore, we can add the elements of the returnValues parameter together to compute the grand total.

Comment: Thank you matthias! Another solution worked however I appreciate your effort as this gave me a better understanding of promise objects.

Comment: You are very welcome. Glad to hear you got it working :)